# How to convert code from Jquery to Javascript

Tags: javascript

How to convert this jquery to Javascript ? 
Thank seen question 
Jquery

```
$(".menu-item").on('click', function() {
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
})
```

Javascript

```
var navDropdownOpen = document.querySelectorAll(".menu-item");

navDropdownOpen.forEach((index)=>{
    index.addEventListener('click', function open_modal() {
        navDropdownOpen.forEach((index)=>{
            if(index.classList.contains('active')) {
                index.classList.remove('active');
            }
            index = index.nextSibling;
        })
        this.classList.toggle('active');
    })
})
```

But toggle remove class last not working

Comment: What have you tried so far? It seems like you did not do any research before asking. Please consider researching more.

Comment: jQuery **is** JavaScript, are you asking for a solution which converts your code to use pure vanilla JavaScript (with no libraries)

Comment: Your code is *already* in JavaScript. The contrast you're looking for is from using jQuery to using the [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model) directly. Knowing that makes it easier to search for the reference information you need. For instance, [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener), and [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).

Comment: You're essentially asking 6 questions at once here. Simply splurging multiple lines of JavaScript and asking how to replace every single library function in them does not make for a good SO question. If you can't find out how to do a **particular** thing without jQuery, then you could ask a more focused question.

Comment: Have a look at [convert jquery to javascript](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/essential-cheat-sheet-convert-jquery-to-javascript--cms-35633)  That's a fairly recent guide on what jquery functions map to vanilla DOM functions and shows examples for each.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder  Sorry, yep - just updated my comment

Comment: i just want understand function siblings()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code in JavaScript

```js
function selectMenu(e) {
    var targetElement = e.target;
    var menuArr = document.getElementsByClassName('menu-item');
    for (var i = 0; i < menuArr.length; i++) {
        var menu = menuArr[i];
        if (menu.classList.contains('active')) {
            menu.classList.remove('active');
        }
    }
    targetElement.classList.add('active');
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
    <div class="menu-item" onClick="selectMenu(event)">Menu1</div>
    <div class="menu-item" onClick="selectMenu(event)">Menu2</div>
    <div class="menu-item" onClick="selectMenu(event)">Menu3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is an object JavaScript is an object orient programming language used to create responsive, interactive elements for web pages, enhancing the user experience.

jQuery is an open-source **JavaScript library** that simplifies the interactions between an HTML/CSS document.(The more detailed version of DOM and JS)

To select the entire HTML
**In JQuery :** `$("html")`
**In JavaScript:** `document.querySelector(selector)`

To select the entire HTML body
**In jQuery:** `$("body")`
**In JavaScript:** `document.body`

I think this will help you to find the answer.

Comment: i understand you can read code me update new thank you